inertiaを使いlaravelにデータをpostしたいのですがデータベース反映されません
環境：php:"8.0.2" inertiajs/react: "^1.0.0" laravel: "9.19" laravel/socialite: "5.15"
inertiaを使ってlaravelにデータをpostしてもデータベースに反映されません。
データ自体は送れていて、スペルミスも無いように思えるのですが、原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けると助かります。
Controller
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        // 認証中のユーザーを取得
        $user = Auth::user();
        // 認証中のユーザーIDを取得
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        // ユーザーがログインしていない場合はログインフォームに移動
        if (!$user) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        $status = 'error';
        // バリデーションの設定
        $request->validate([
            'store_name' => 'required|string|max:20',
            'location' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'text' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
        ]);

        // トライキャッチ構文で処理を書く
        try {
            // トランザクション開始
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $storeModel = new Store();

            $store = $storeModel->saveStore([
                'user_id' => $id,
                'store_name' => $request->store_name,
                'location' => $request->location,
                'text' => $request->text,
                'created_by' => $id,
                'updated_by' => $id,
            ]);
            // コミット
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            Log::error($message);
            DB::rollBack(); // エラーならDBをロールバックする
            throw $e;
        }
        // ステータス
        if ($store) {
            $status = 'store-created';
        }

        // リダイレクトでマイページに飛ばす
        return redirect()->route('user.index', [
            'status' => $status,
        ]);
    }

inertia/React
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MainLayout from '@/layouts/MainLayout';
import { Avatar, Box, Button, FormControl, FormLabel, Heading, HStack, Input, Textarea} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { router, usePage } from '@inertiajs/react';
const Create = (props) => {
    const { auth, csrf_token } = usePage().props;
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        store_name: "",
        location: "",
        text: "",
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setData({...data, [name]: value});
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(data);
        router.post(route('store.register'), {
            _token: csrf_token,
            data,
        });
    };
    return (
        <Box p={4} m={4} mx={"auto"} w={{ base:"90%", md: 700 }}>

            <Heading display='flex' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' fontSize={{ base:18,md:24 }} as="h2" md={4}>
                編集
            </Heading>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Box bg="#ebebeb" borderWidth={"1px"} borderRadius={"lg"} overflow={"hidden"} md={4}>
            <Box p={4} display='flex' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
            <HStack spacing={4} px={2}>
            <Avatar
            name="Avatar"
            src="https://bit.ly/broken-link"
            />
            <Heading as="h3" size="sd">User_name</Heading>
            <Button as="a" bg="#ffff">Change Photo</Button>
            </HStack>
            </Box>
            </Box>

            <FormControl isRequired mb={4}>
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="store_name" fontWeight={"bold"}>store_name</FormLabel>
                    <Input
                    type="text"
                    id="store_name"
                    name="store_name"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl isRequired id="location" mb={4}>
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="location" fontWeight={"bold"}>location</FormLabel>
                    <Input
                    type="text"
                    id="location"
                    name="location"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl isRequired mb={4}>
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="text" fontWeight={"bold"}>text</FormLabel>
                    <Textarea id="text" name="text" onChange={handleChange}></Textarea>
            </FormControl>
            <Button type="submit" colorScheme="blue" mt={4} mb={4}>
                登録
            </Button>
            </form>

        </Box>
    );
}
Create.layout = (page) => <MainLayout children={page} title={"登録"}  />
export default Create;



試したこと
Controllerの
$request->validate([
            'store_name' => 'required|string|max:20',
            'location' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'text' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
        ]);

をコメントアウトし、再度確認
エラー文を調べたところ、生合成規約違反と出ました。store_nameはstring型なのですが、送ったデータが型と一致しないのか、そもそもデータがどこかで止まっているのか、頭を悩ませています。
どうかご教授お願いします。


スマホからの書き込みで失礼します。
手元に開発機がなく、実際に動かしてないので予測になってしまいますが、データが正常に取得できていないのかと思います。
$request->store_name とPOSTした値を取得しようとしていますが、以下の形を真似してもらえれば取得できるようになるかと思います
$validated = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

dd($validated['title']);
// もしくは以下でも
dd($request->input('title'));


Requestクラスの使用方法は以下の公式ドキュメントを参照してください
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/requests
参考になりましたら幸いです。
